# Конфликт между процессами multiprocessing.Process и QTimer на форме

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pyqt5, multiprocessing

Имеется процесс типа multiprocessing.Process, в целевой функции сериализующий данные с помощью pickle. И имеется окно, обновляющее график по тику таймера QTimer с помощью данных из того же файла.

Если при дебаге останавливаться только внутри **процесса**, то всё выглядит так, будто сериализация проходит нормально.

Если останавливаться только в работе **по таймеру**, то всё время файл как будто пуст.

Если поставить брекпоинты в обоих местах, то наблюдается следующее поведение:

**В процессе:**

```
    def run(self):
        while True:
            to_dump = []
            for i in self.processes.values():  # после этой строчки перепрыгивает к брекпоинту в функции по таймеру
                to_dump.append((i.get_name(), i.get_time()))  # вид данных на запись: (str, float)
            with open("bars.pickle", mode="wb") as barsfile:
                pickle.dump(to_dump, barsfile)
            time.sleep(0.2)
```

**По таймеру**

```
i = 0
try:
    with open("bars.pickle", mode="rb") as barsfile: # брекпоинт
        bar_data = pickle.load(barsfile)
    for p_name, p_time in bar_data:  # после этой строки уходит вообще из этого отрезка кода
        self.axes.bar(p_name, p_time, color='g')
        i = i + 1
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

В чем может быть дело?

При этом в программе связь процесса и окна с помощью pickle есть ещё в одном месте -- и там всё ок.

Это учебный проект, в котором необходимо использовать процессы и GUI. У меня PyQt5, в котором, насколько я поняла, больше нет QProcess -- значит, заменить multiprocessing.Process на него (и так перейти к передаче данных через сигнал/слот) не выйдет. Пользоваться очередями между моими "бэкграунд"-процессами и процессом формы не выйдет.

**UPDATE**

После удаления строки `time.sleep(0.2)` поведение не стало более понятным, однако теперь иногда то, что нужно, сериализуется в объект, а потом десериализуется. (А иногда не десериализуется -- как будто файл пустой).

Минимальный пример:

```
import sys
import pickle
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from multiprocessing import Process


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = QLabel("text", self)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_lab)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        self.show()

    def update_lab(self):
        with open("label.txt", mode="rb") as f:
            lab = pickle.load(f)
        print("we get " + str(lab))
        self.label.setText(lab)

class SubProcess:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = Process(target=self.run)
        self.x = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
            a = 2+2

    def get_x(self):
        self.x += 1
        return self.x

class HeadProcess:
    def __init__(self):
        self.processes = {}
        self.process = Process(target=self.run)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            to_dump = []
            for i in self.processes:
                to_dump.append(i.get_x())
            print("we put" + str(to_dump))
            with open("label.txt", mode="wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(to_dump, f)
        pass

    def create_process(self):
        new_process = SubProcess()
        self.processes[new_process.process.name] = new_process
        new_process.process.start()
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()

    hp = HeadProcess()
    hp.process.start()
    hp.create_process()
    hp.create_process()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Тяжело дать вам совет без наличия минимального примера демонстрирующего проблему, меня заинтересовало ваше высказывание: 'У меня PyQt5, в котором, насколько я поняла, больше нет QProcess'. А куда он делся ?

Класс `QProcess` используется для запуска внешних программ и для связи с ними. Вот пример:

```
import sys    
import psutil     # pip install psutil
from PyQt5        import QtCore, QtWidgets      
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QProcess


class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    update_progressbar = pyqtSignal(float)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            val = psutil.cpu_percent()
            QThread.msleep(260)                               
            self.update_progressbar.emit(val)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUi()

        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadclass.start()
        self.threadclass.update_progressbar.connect(self.update_progressbar)

        self.process = QProcess()                                      # <-------
        self.process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self.process.start("python", ["-u", "file_import.py"])

    def update_progressbar(self, val):
        self.progressBar.setValue(val)

    def  initUi(self):
        self.resize(595, 156)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 40, 391, 51))
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Using the CPU", self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 141, 31))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Переопределить colseEvent
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question\
        (self, 'Информация',
            "Вы уверены, что хотите уйти?",
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.process.kill()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a   = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = MainWindow()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, точно. Извините, я вас запутала. QProcess ведь используется для запуска внешних программ, а тут нужна связь с другими процессами тут же. Добавила минимальный пример